# Adding same element to every level of array php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to add another another element to each level of the array (sorry, think that is bad terminology).

I have an array -

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
      [actor_rt_id] => 162683283,
      [item_number] => 3 ) 
         [1] => Array ( 
      [actor_rt_id] => 162657351,
       [item_number] => 5 ) 
)
```

This code produces the array. The commented out line is what I tried to add to the array. The code before the comment creates the array.

```
$data_itemone['actor_rt_id'] = $this->input->post('actor_id');
$data_itemtwo['item_number'] = $this->input->post('item_number');
$data_item = array_merge($data_itemone, $data_itemtwo);
$res = [];
    foreach($data_item as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value as $data => $thevalue) {
            $res[$data][$key] = $thevalue;
            //$res['film_id'] = $film_id;
        }
    }
```

I have an another variable I need to add from post which is a single string.

```
 $film_id = $this->input->post('film_id');
```

I need it to be in the array like so -

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
          [actor_rt_id] => 162683283,
          [item_number] => 3,
          [film_id]    => 52352
          ) 
             [1] => Array ( 
          [actor_rt_id] => 162657351,
          [item_number] => 5,
          [film_id]    => 52352
          ) 
)
```

...but my code (uncommented) produces -

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
        [actor_rt_id] => 162683283,
        [item_number] => 3 
      )
        [film_id] => 16639,
        [1] => Array 
                ( [actor_rt_id] => 162657351,
                  [item_number] => 5 )
 )
```

Tried a few things. Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: The `$data_itemone` and `$data_itemtwo` part is confusing. Where are you getting the array contents from?

Comment: They come from form inputs with the same name like name="actor_id[]", but there are multiple inputs so it produces an array. I did the merge so that they would produce an array in the format that I need. ...so $data_itemone and $data_itemtwo are arrays, but $film_id is only a single string. ...but I need to add it in the array I like showed.

Comment: film_id is 1 single number that will be the same in each iteration of the array.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($myArray, function($value) use ($film_id) { if (is_array($value)) { $value['film_id'] = $film_id; } else { $value = array(0 => $value, 'film_id' => $film_id; }});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`$res['film_id'] = $film_id;`

to

`$res[$data]['film_id'] = $film_id;`

this will add it to the right array.

Comment: Oh thank you! I knew it was something in brackets like that but that was a combo I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

How if you try this.

```
$data_itemone['actor_rt_id'] = [123, 245];
$data_itemtwo['item_number'] = [456, 789];
$film_id = 52352;
$data_item = array_merge($data_itemone, $data_itemtwo);
$res = [];
foreach($data_item as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $data => $thevalue) {
        $res[$data][$key] = $thevalue;
        $res[$data]['film_id'] = $film_id;
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?
    $data_itemone['actor_rt_id'] = $this->input->post('actor_id');
    $data_itemtwo['item_number'] = $this->input->post('item_number');
    $film_id = $this->input->post('film_id');
    $data_item = array_merge($data_itemone, $data_itemtwo);
    $res = [];
    foreach($data_item as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value as $data => $thevalue) {
            $res[$data][$key] = $thevalue;
            $res[$data]['film_id'] = $film_id;
        }
    }
?>
```